# Azure APIM control which APIs are shown in the developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to publish a developer portal for our APIM instance for the first time, but most of the APIs in our APIM are for internal use only and I don't want them in the developer portal.  Is there an easy way to pick which APIs show up in the developer portal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API visibility is controlled through products and groups. You can assign user groups to a product to expose it and its APIs to users of that group. Most likely right now you see all APIs since you act as an admin. Try logging into dev portal as a normal user.

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy,  this had occurred to me after I posted this.  So I created a user and assigned them only to the product/API that I wanted them to see.  However, when I try to log in as that user, I just get this non descriptive error "Oops. Something went wrong. Please try again later."  Any ideas here?

Comment: This worth opening support request. In simple scenarios it should not happen, in more complex ones may be result of third party dependencies, like AAD, if one is configured.